# How to access files that are committed inside GitHub Actions?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Our GitHub Action workflow executes when we commit a file on GitHub that files could be any doc file. Inside GitHub Actions run .exe file, that is generating HTML files based on doc file. That HTML files are committed inside the same GitHub workflow actions. We are trying to deploy these HTML files on another Repository. Before this we have tried to get these HTML files inside the same GitHub action workflow, for example, ls "path", checked with the latest commit(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA") it returns committed id that is committed from Github but we want that committed id or files that committed inside GitHub workflow actions. We couldn't get that Html Files.

We would appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you do _after_ you do the commit?  Do you push it?

Comment: Yes, push it, and then that file will be available on GitHub Repository,